Sum of derivative of polynomial over its simple roots
Let $P$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb C$, and $n\in\mathbb N$ be a positive integer. I'm interested in the root sums of the form
$$ \sum_{P(x)=0}\frac{1}{P'(x)^n},$$
where the sum runs over all roots of $P$, which we assume to be distinct (simple roots). Since $P'$ is a polynomial, we sum a rational function over the roots of polynomial, which using the elementary symmetric polynomials gives a rational function in the coefficients of $P$. I'm in particular interested in the denominator of that rational function, since I want to study the "singular" behaviour of the root sum.
Motivation: These sums occur in calculations of partition functions in physics.
Goal: Express this as a function of $P$ and $n$. Intermediate goal: Express the denominator as a function of $P$ and $n$.
My approach: Using examples and Mathematica's RootSum, I found a conjecture:
$$ \sum_{P(x)=0}\frac{1}{P'(x)^n}=\frac{Q(P)}{D(P)^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}}$$
Here, $D(P)$ denotes the discriminant of the polynomial $P$, $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function, and $Q(P)$ is a polynomial in the coefficients of $P$.
For $n=1$, this sum is zero, as one can prove using the residue theorem (see e.g. the answer sum of reciprocals of derivative of polynomial at its roots). This might explain the "odd" exponents for $n$ odd.
I am not sure how to prove such a statement (in case it is correct). I assume it will be useful that the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_j(P')$ of the derivative are related as $e_j(P')=(n-j)e_j(P)$, but I don't see how to compute these sums by hand. Any hints are appreciated!

For $P(x)=\prod (x-\alpha_i)$ we have just $P'(\alpha_i)=\prod_{j\neq i}(\alpha _i-\alpha_j)$. So the common denominator in $\sum\frac{1}{P'(\alpha_i)^n}$ must be just a product of such terms for distinct $i,j$ to power $n$ (and numerator is a symmetric polynomial in roots so it must be a polynomial in coefficients of $P$).

Great, thanks! Any insights on the cancellation for $n$ odd?

Not really, I guess a natural step would be to write out the numerator before cancellation and trying to show it is divisible by $\alpha_i-\alpha_j$ for any $i\neq j$ (when viewed as a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k]$).

Right. I find that the numerator is an alternating sum of $\sum_{i<j, i\neq k}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^n$ over $k=1,\dots, n$ (I haven't worked out the signs). This does seem to factorise into $\sum_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$ and a polynomial in the $x_i$ for $n$ odd, but I'm not able to prove this
